# Crop image to biggest centred part with a ratio

Tags: python, ruby, linux, shell, imagemagick

I would like to crop image to a radio, 4:3 for instance.

But I would like the biggest centred part, for instance :

[image: From 1] to [image: To 1]

[image: From 2] to [image: To 2]

I didn't find my situation in [the imagemagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop).

(Imgur sizes are quite inacurate but you should get the idea)

Comment: This can be done in Python using the PIL module and a little math. See my answer to the question [What's the simplest way in Python to resize an image to a given bounded area?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3873859/355230).

Comment: Thanks the answer is exactly what I needed, but I wanted a one-line command.

Comment: The technique presented in the well documented code in my referenced answer -- if not the code itself -- could easily be used to create a one-line command. I figured them out many years ago and have since implemented them in several different languages and/or used them with different image-manipulation libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I wrote a little script for me: [reduce-ration](https://gist.github.com/Dorian/4969638) (it requires ruby with the fastimage gem: `gem install fastimage`)

In my example: `reduce-maxi 4x3 center shutup.png templerun.jpg`

You can use it like: `reduce-maxi RATIO DIRECTION IMAGES...`. See [the gist](https://gist.github.com/Dorian/4969638) for more details.

I also wrote a script to get the ratio of the images. See [the gist](https://gist.github.com/Dorian/4969638).