# Return values from a nested function and update the main values inside a callable class

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, nested

So, the problem that I face and that I am trying to fix is the following. I am using the second part of the tkinter code from this guy (martineau) here: [Selecting an area of an image with a mouse and recording the dimensions of the selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636313/selecting-an-area-of-an-image-with-a-mouse-and-recording-the-dimensions-of-the-s/55772675?noredirect=1#comment125597083_55772675)

I have taken the code and made it a callable class like this:

```
class select_area_class:
    def __call__(self):
        import tkinter as tk
        from PIL import Image, ImageTk 
        
        WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 900
        topx, topy, botx, boty = 0, 0, 0, 0

        . . . 

        canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', update_sel_rect)

        window.mainloop()
```

The problem is that when this function is called:

```
def get_mouse_posn(event):
    global topy, topx

    topx, topy = event.x, event.y
    . . .
```

(by the way I have erased this command:  `global topy, topx` because it was throwing me an error, so, I have made it like this:

```
def get_mouse_posn(event):

    topx, topy = event.x, event.y
    . . .
```

)

it does not update the main values: `topx, topy`. So, anywhere I place the mouse inside the widget, I get as initial position the (0,0). I have tried to return `event.x, event.y` but I cannot figure out how to read the return values from this command:

```
canvas.bind('<Button-1>', get_mouse_posn)
```

in order to update the main variables `topx, topy` and so to make the code work.... I have read both how canvas work (here: https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) and how bind works (here: https://web.archive.org/web/20201111211515id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm ), but I cannot find a way to make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: Removing the `global` statement directly causes the values to not get updated outside the function. What is that error you mentioned?

Comment: Ok, I enabled the global variables. It throws me this error:   `File "test_code.py", line 327, in update_sel_rect
    canvas.coords(rect_id, topx, topy, botx, boty)  # Update selection rect.
NameError: name 'rect_id' is not defined`   but I see  that enabling the other global variables and disabling only this: `global rect_id` that it works!! Do I need `rect_id` ? So, the global variables are limited inside the specific class as I understand, right??

Comment: I don't know if _you_ need `rect_id` but presumably it has a purpose in the code. You may want to be careful with using global variables too, there is probably a different way to implement what you need.

Comment: If you have used class, why don't you use *instance variables* instead of *global variables*?

Comment: @acw1668: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have used class, it is better to use *instance variables* instead of *global variables*.

Also change `get_mouse_posn()` and `update_sel_rect()` to class methods as well.

Below is a simple example based on your posted code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class select_area_class:
    def __call__(self):
        window = tk.Tk()

        WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 900
        # use instance variables
        self.topx, self.topy, self.botx, self.boty = 0, 0, 0, 0

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', self.get_mouse_posn)
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.update_sel_rect)

        window.mainloop()

    def get_mouse_posn(self, event):
        self.topx, self.topy = self.botx, self.boty = event.x, event.y
        self.rect_id = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.topx, self.topy, self.botx, self.boty, outline='red')

    def update_sel_rect(self, event):
        self.botx, self.boty = event.x, event.y
        self.canvas.coords(self.rect_id, self.topx, self.topy, self.botx, self.boty)


a = select_area_class()
a()
```

Note: *Is it necessary to make the class callable?*