# How use the image width and height as the variable for the application window size

Tags: python, tkinter

I have cobbled together the below code (original source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636313/selecting-an-area-of-an-image-with-a-mouse-and-recording-the-dimensions-of-the-s#comment97970839_55636313))

I can't work out how to use the image width and height for driving the application width and height

I want the application window to be the same size as the source image.

---

Here's the code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class MousePositionTracker(tk.Frame):
    """ Tkinter Canvas mouse position widget. """

    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.canv_width = self.canvas.cget('width')
        self.canv_height = self.canvas.cget('height')
        self.reset()

        # Create canvas cross-hair lines.
        xhair_opts = dict(dash=(3, 2), fill='white', state=tk.HIDDEN)
        self.lines = (self.canvas.create_line(0, 0, 0, self.canv_height, **xhair_opts),
                      self.canvas.create_line(0, 0, self.canv_width,  0, **xhair_opts))

    def cur_selection(self):
        return (self.start, self.end)

    def begin(self, event):
        self.hide()
        self.start = (event.x, event.y)  # Remember position (no drawing).

    def update(self, event):
        self.end = (event.x, event.y)
        self._update(event)
        self._command(self.start, (event.x, event.y))  # User callback.

    def _update(self, event):
        # Update cross-hair lines.
        self.canvas.coords(self.lines[0], event.x, 0, event.x, self.canv_height)
        self.canvas.coords(self.lines[1], 0, event.y, self.canv_width, event.y)
        self.show()

    def reset(self):
        self.start = self.end = None

    def hide(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.lines[0], state=tk.HIDDEN)
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.lines[1], state=tk.HIDDEN)

    def show(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.lines[0], state=tk.NORMAL)
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.lines[1], state=tk.NORMAL)

    def autodraw(self, command=lambda *args: None):
        """Setup automatic drawing; supports command option"""
        self.reset()
        self._command = command
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.begin)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.update)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.quit)

    def quit(self, event):
        self.hide()  # Hide cross-hairs.
        self.reset()


class SelectionObject:
    """ Widget to display a rectangular area on given canvas defined by two points
        representing its diagonal.
    """
    def __init__(self, canvas, select_opts):
        # Create attributes needed to display selection.
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.select_opts1 = select_opts
        self.width = self.canvas.cget('width')
        self.height = self.canvas.cget('height')

        # Options for areas outside rectanglar selection.
        select_opts1 = self.select_opts1.copy()  # Avoid modifying passed argument.
        select_opts1.update(state=tk.HIDDEN)  # Hide initially.
        # Separate options for area inside rectanglar selection.
        select_opts2 = dict(dash=(2, 2), fill='', outline='white', state=tk.HIDDEN)

        # Initial extrema of inner and outer rectangles.
        imin_x, imin_y,  imax_x, imax_y = 0, 0,  1, 1
        omin_x, omin_y,  omax_x, omax_y = 0, 0,  self.width, self.height

        self.rects = (
            # Area *outside* selection (inner) rectangle.
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(omin_x, omin_y,  omax_x, imin_y, **select_opts1),
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(omin_x, imin_y,  imin_x, imax_y, **select_opts1),
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(imax_x, imin_y,  omax_x, imax_y, **select_opts1),
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(omin_x, imax_y,  omax_x, omax_y, **select_opts1),
            # Inner rectangle.
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(imin_x, imin_y,  imax_x, imax_y, **select_opts2)
        )

    def update(self, start, end):
        # Current extrema of inner and outer rectangles.
        imin_x, imin_y,  imax_x, imax_y = self._get_coords(start, end)
        omin_x, omin_y,  omax_x, omax_y = 0, 0,  self.width, self.height

        # Update coords of all rectangles based on these extrema.
        self.canvas.coords(self.rects[0], omin_x, omin_y,  omax_x, imin_y),
        self.canvas.coords(self.rects[1], omin_x, imin_y,  imin_x, imax_y),
        self.canvas.coords(self.rects[2], imax_x, imin_y,  omax_x, imax_y),
        self.canvas.coords(self.rects[3], omin_x, imax_y,  omax_x, omax_y),
        self.canvas.coords(self.rects[4], imin_x, imin_y,  imax_x, imax_y),

        for rect in self.rects:  # Make sure all are now visible.
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(rect, state=tk.NORMAL)

        # Update bounding box result
        global bounding_box

        bounding_box = self._get_coords(start, end)

        # # Print result on every change
        # print("Bounding Box Result:")
        # print(f"Top Left: ({bounding_box[0]}, {bounding_box[1]})")
        # print(f"Bottom Right: ({bounding_box[2]}, {bounding_box[3]})\n")

    def _get_coords(self, start, end):
        """ Determine coords of a polygon defined by the start and
            end points one of the diagonals of a rectangular area.
        """
        return (min((start[0], end[0])), min((start[1], end[1])),
                max((start[0], end[0])), max((start[1], end[1])))

    def hide(self):
        for rect in self.rects:
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(rect, state=tk.HIDDEN)


class Application(tk.Frame):

    # Default selection object options.
    SELECT_OPTS = dict(dash=(2, 2), stipple='gray25', fill='black',
                          outline='')

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        path = "/Users/nathan/Desktop/Books.jpeg"
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=img.width(), height=img.height(),
                                borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)

        self.canvas.pack(expand=True)

        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor=tk.NW)
        self.canvas.img = img  # Keep reference.

        # Create selection object to show current selection boundaries.
        self.selection_obj = SelectionObject(self.canvas, self.SELECT_OPTS)

        # Callback function to update it given two points of its diagonal.
        def on_drag(start, end, **kwarg):  # Must accept these arguments.
            self.selection_obj.update(start, end)

        # Create mouse position tracker that uses the function.
        self.posn_tracker = MousePositionTracker(self.canvas)
        self.posn_tracker.autodraw(command=on_drag)  # Enable callbacks.

        # # Create a button to close the application.
        # self.close_button = tk.Button(root, text="Close", command=self.close_application)
        # self.close_button.pack()

        # Bind the Escape and Enter keys to the close_application method.
        root.bind("<Escape>", self.close_application)
        root.bind("<Return>", self.close_application)

    def close_application(self, event=None):
        try:
            print(bounding_box)
        except: 
            print("None")
        root.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':




    # Set the size and position of the application window.


    BACKGROUND = '#282A36'
    TITLE = 'Image Cropper'
    WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1280, 720

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title(TITLE)
    root.configure(background=BACKGROUND)

    # Get the screen width and height
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

    # Calculate the position to center the window
    x = (screen_width - WIDTH) // 2
    y = (screen_height - HEIGHT) // 2

    # Set the window geometry
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (WIDTH, HEIGHT, x, y))



    # # Make the window fullscreen
    # root.state('zoomed')

    # # Make the window borderless
    # root.overrideredirect(True)

    app = Application(root, background=BACKGROUND)
    app.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)
    app.mainloop()
```

What I tried to do:

I tried to define a global variable.

I found that the width and height of the application window is defined at the end of the code (line 185)
source image is defined within 'class Application(tk.Frame)' (line 135)

I'm not sure if I am misunderstanding global variables, or something else. But I can't work out how to populate the `WIDTH, HEIGHT` (line 185) with values from the image.

I tried adding

```
global image_size
image_size = img.width(),img.height()
```

to 'class Application(tk.Frame)'

and then using that, like so

```
WIDTH, HEIGHT = image_size
```

but this does not work, would anyone mind giving me a hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already setting the size of the canvas to the size of the image, and the way the app is configured the window will shrink or grow to fit the image. Just remove `root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (WIDTH, HEIGHT, x, y))` and the window should automatically be the size you want.

If you want the window to remain positioned at the given x,y, then specify the geometry with the x/y coordinates but not with the width/height values.

```
root.geometry('+%d+%d' % (x, y))
```

Comment: Hey Bryan, thanks for getting back to me. This does work, but it no longer centres the image on the screen. I actually managed to hack it to work. I am happy to mark your answer as correct, but would you know the best approach to maintain entering the app window?

Comment: Related, but not specific to my original question…
Would it be possible without too much issue to set a specific size for the app window, and have the contents scale down to fit?

Comment: @Nathan: You can specify a value for the geometry that does not include the width and height. I've updated my answer to illustrate that.

Comment: @Nathan: you will have to manage the scaling of the image yourself using functions available in PIL.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, Im all sorted out now :)